# Question marks in Flask Urls for routing

Tags: python-2.7, flask, routes, werkzeug

So, I have the following route in Flask:

```
@app.route("/menu-card/<google_place_id>", methods=['GET'])
```

On navigating to http://127.0.0.1:5000/menu-card/ChIJAxXhIUMUrjsR5QOqVsQjCCI, I get the proper response.

However, then I tried changing the URL pattern as follows:

```
@app.route("/menu-card?id=<google_place_id>", methods=['GET'])
```

On navigating to http://127.0.0.1:5000/menu-card?id=ChIJAxXhIUMUrjsR5QOqVsQjCCI I now get a 404 error. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The part after the `?` is the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), which you can get using `request.args`.  So, your route should be:

```
@app.route("/menu-card", methods=['GET'])
```

and then you can get the id by using:

```
google_place_id = request.args.get('id', None)
```

where `None` is the default value, if `id` is not included in the url.  You'll have to check if that it's not equal to `None` to make sure it has been passed.

Search [the quickstart page for `request.args`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#the-request-object) to see another example.

Comment: thanks..exactly what I wanted..

Comment: Link is dead, here is the [official documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.args)

Comment: Thanks @RunOrVeith, fixed the link